# Appending new arrays to the documents directory

Tags: arrays, swift, nsdocumentdirectory

I am saving an array of coordinates to the documents directory.

In order to add further arrays of coordinates I have constructed an array of arrays, with the inner array containing dictionaries of coordinates).

As such, on the first save the content will look like this:

```
[
   [
      {
         "lat":123,
         "long":-0.123
      },
      {
         "lat":234,
         "long":-0.234
      }
   ]
]
```

On subsequent saves I will add new groupings of coordinates.

How can I append to this array in the documents directory, so that it could look like a valid JSON like this.

```
[
   [
      {
         "lat":123,
         "long":-0.123
      },
      {
         "lat":234,
         "long":-0.234
      }
   ],
   [
      {
         "lat":345,
         "long":-0.345
      }
   ]
]
```

For example. Should I read the contents of the documents directory and insert the new array, then overwrite the original file (not something I particulary want to do as the file will become large very quickly).

Or is there a way to append directly to the file?

Comment: We cannot able to append a data in document. So, first get a data from document and append additional datas and then write in document.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        
      
        let str = """
            [
                [
                    {
                    "lat":123,
                    "long":-0.123
                    },
                    {
                    "lat":123,
                    "long":-0.123
                    }
                ]
            ]

          """
        
        
        let appendedStr = """

            [
                {
                "lat":123,
                "long":-0.123
                },
                {
                "lat":123,
                "long":-0.123
                }
            ]


        """
        
        do {
            
            var res = try JSONDecoder().decode([[Root]].self, from: str.data(using: .utf8)!)
            
            print(res)
            
            let app = try JSONDecoder().decode([Root].self, from: appendedStr.data(using: .utf8)!)
            
            res.append(app)
            
            print(res) 

            let dataToStore = try JSONEncoder().encode(res)
            
            print(dataToStore)
        }
        catch {
            
            print(error)
        }

    }
}

struct Root: Codable {
    let lat: Int
    let long: Double
}
```

Output

> [[dsdsd.Root(lat: 123, long: -0.123), dsdsd.Root(lat: 123, long: -0.123)]]
>
> [[dsdsd.Root(lat: 123, long: -0.123), dsdsd.Root(lat: 123, long: -0.123)], [dsdsd.Root(lat: 123, long: -0.123), dsdsd.Root(lat: 123, long: -0.123)]]
>
> 109 bytes

Comment: Thanks. I will look into this.